# CSS fixed container in IE6

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

```
#fixed {
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:1000px;
}
```

how can i make this element display the same way in IE6? the div is the first element directly in the body
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 6 doesn't support `position: fixed` ([Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html)) and there is no easy CSS-only workaround as far as I know.

You would need to employ a JavaScript based workaround solution that adjusts the element's position when the page gets scrolled.

There's a very simple solution outlined in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257250/what-is-the-simplest-jquery-way-to-have-a-positionfixed-always-at-top-div). Those JS based solutions tend to be pretty jiggly and jerky in my experience, they are nowhere near the smoothness of `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry don't have time to translate my sample with your exact requirements but take inspiration with those code :

```
// Modern browser : FF, Chrome, Opera
// ----------------------------------------

#fixmetoo { position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
div > div#fixmetoo { position: fixed; }


// IE6
-------------------------------------------

<!--[if lt IE 7]>
div#fixmetoo {
        right: auto; bottom: auto;
        left: expression( ( -80 - fixmetoo.offsetWidth + ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : document.body.clientWidth ) + ( ignoreMe2 = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft ) ) + 'px' );
        top: expression( ( -100 - fixmetoo.offsetHeight + ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight ) + ( ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop ) ) + 'px' );
    }
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: great, except it's fixed relative to the bottom and not centered. I don't quite follow the ignoreMe n such. What i need is center top.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you could try this css - then the element is centered.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
#fixed {
margin: 0 auto; 
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```