# Change a div tag from fixed to absolute and back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fixed, absolute

In the Facebook News Feed, the side bar (containing ads, etc.) isn't fixed all the time. How do you do this?
You could do

```
<div style="position:fixed"></div>
```

But how could you tell it to change back and forth according to your wish?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy to do it with jQuery:

```
$("#sideBar").css("position", "fixed");
```

and then to change it back:

```
$("#sideBar").css("position", "");
```

Comment: +1 I missed the jQuery tag, and you beat me by a few seconds. :-)

Comment: I think the question is about the whole process involved in this behavior of an element. He want the entire script, including scroll events and others.. that's why I voted down his question

Comment: @MateiMihai in that case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257250/what-is-the-simplest-jquery-way-to-have-a-positionfixed-always-at-top-div