# Making a Div Display When Clicked Wherever the Page is

Tags: jquery, css

I have one page site that scrolls. I have a navgation menu that remains at the top of the browser at all times. One of the list items is the contact page. I'd like to have a div fadeIn (which I have no trouble doing with jQuery), wherever you happen to be on the page. So I was wondering how do I define it's position? For instance, If I am scrolled half way down the page, and click the contact link, can it just appear right there vs say back up at the top of the page?

Comment: Yes it can. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try the answers posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257250/what-is-the-simplest-jquery-way-to-have-a-positionfixed-always-at-top-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `position:fixed;` on your contact div. With a simple JS script, you can dynamically set the top and left attribute to position the div in the center of the screen.

`fixed` position is relative to the viewport.
`absolute` position is relative to the document.

You can test these CSS properties on [this w3school example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_position&preval=fixed). Reduce your browser height to add a scroll bar and compare the result of fixed vs absolute position.

**EDIT :**  [basic fixed position popup](http://jsfiddle.net/zgQVF/2/) (Fiddle)

You can get the viewport size with `$(window).width()` or `$(window).height()`. Then you can get the popup div size with equivalent jQuery method on the jQuery object. And finally, you calculate the correct position with : (viewPortSize/2) - (divSize/2).

Please note that if the div is not visible (`display:none` for example), its size will be 0 ! That's why I call the `.fadeIn()` function before positioning the popup to be sure that the div will be visible.

Comment: Thanks. I think this will work. I'm still pretty much a beginner at JS. I know I can set the left and right attributes, but how can I make them dynamic to the page?

Comment: I have edited my post with a link to a fiddle showing a pretty basic popup example. If the answer helped, don't forget to mark it resolved and to upvote it. ;)