# div always on top of page and random image automatically fit that div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, height, width

Excuse my ignorance and let me explain.

I would like a div to be always fully visible in a web-page. 
Its a div that contains a random picture and after that is a "Read more" button . So it would be nice if the image fits the div and the div and the button are always visible, when the page is fully scrolled up.

So, its the header and then the "container div". Inside the "container div", the first thing on top is that "read more" div. Not `position : fixed` cause this does not work well in mobiles. I guess I have to do something like

```
width : 50%
height : 
get the current height of the screen - height of the header = this is where it begins
get the current height of the screen - height of the footer - height of a text - height of a button = this is where it stops
```

But how do I do this? The height to be a result of the screen's dimensions, and based on percent rates, so its also responsive design

Also, the div contains a random image that have to be automatically resized to fit and not get stretched.

By random I mean its maybe "portrait shaped" or maybe "landscape shaped". I read this [article](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images/) but setting only `width:100%` stretches "portrait shaped" images.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Sorry for my english.[image]

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or a plunker?

Comment: Something like this? or am I missing your point? http://jsfiddle.net/sCrAZ/

Comment: @Chad Sorry, not like that. I dont want to use `position fixed` because I want the image to scroll along with the page. And also, `position fixed` gets buggy in mobiles.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige Not so much experienced with fiddle, I try to load images, but I cannot. Sorry...

Comment: If you dont want to use position fixed you would have to use javascript. There should be lots of jQuery plugins for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige I fix the fiddle! Here you go `http://jsfiddle.net/slevin/kNgpt/`. The image and the button should always be in display, when the page is scrolled up. So they have to re-size automatically

Answer (score 1):

For the fixed position, you can use this solution, as posted here: [What is the simplest jQuery way to have a 'position:fixed' (always at top) div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257250/what-is-the-simplest-jquery-way-to-have-a-positionfixed-always-at-top-div)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.headup').css('top', $(this).scrollTop() + "px");
});
```

For the image, you can use max-width:

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9sTXa/